# SET lc_messages = 'en_US' - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages' EVEN the version is updated

Tags: php, apache, wamp

My phpmyadmin when ever I try to connect to mysql it gives me this error :

> SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
>
> MySQL said: Documentation 1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

my php version : 7.2.14

my apach version :2.4.37

MySQL :5.7.24

I don't get it why it dosnt work with this version but when I change it my php version to : 5.6.4 it works . But I can't use it now because my project uses the php version : 7.1 . So I am obliged to make it work with Higher version.

Can you please give me some guidence where the problem come from .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have two sql running in the same systeme . So i deleted the processor of sql server with task manager and rerun my wamp server and it seems everything works fine.